# T-SQL Join Date to Nearest Date with Non-Zero Value in Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have `table`:

```
id    date  
1     2018-03-20
1     2018-02-05      
3     2018-03-18       
7     2018-03-12
```

I have `table_2`:

```
id    date_2         value
1     2018-03-20     0   
1     2018-03-19     100 
1     2018-02-05     50   
3     2018-03-18     200
```

I would like to join these to produce one table that looks like this:

```
id    date         date_2       value
1     2018-03-20   2018-03-19   100   
1     2018-02-05   2018-02-05   50
3     2018-03-18   2018-03-18   200   
7     2018-03-12   NULL         NULL
```

If `date` corresponds to a record in `table_2` that has a non-zero value, then that record should be returned. If `date` corresponds to a record in `table_2` that has a `value` of `0` or does not exist in `table_2`, then the record with the most recent `date_2` prior to `date` should be returned (provided it has a non-zero value).

In the tables, `id` `1` with `date` `2018-03-20` correlates to a record that has `value` `0`. Therefore, the record from `table_2` with `date_2` of `2018-03-19` should be returned.

How would I join these tables to arrive at this result?

Comment: Why 1     2018-03-20   2018-03-20   0   is not in the output? Why date_2 is 19th March instead of 20th in the very first row of output?

Comment: Your expected result data does not look correct based on your explanation, shouldn't the first row have a value of 100 and the second row have a value of 200?

Comment: I agree, the logic should be consistent and then you can easily join to the nearest dates using LEAD or LAG function.

Comment: Edited - thanks for the heads up. @Aurelian - could you please post a solution with lead/lag? I would be interested in how that option works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using outer apply:

Editing based on comment that ID is also part of join

```
declare @t1 as table (id int,  date1 date)
insert into @t1 
values 
(1,     '2018-03-20')     
,(3,     '2018-03-18')

,(7,     '2018-03-12')  


declare @t2 as table(
id int,    date_2  date       ,value int)
insert into @t2
values
(1     ,'2018-03-20',     0   )
,(1     ,'2018-03-19'    , 100    )
,(3     ,'2018-03-18',     200) 



select t.* ,t2.date_2,t2.value
from @t1 t
outer apply (select top 1 date_2
                  , value 
             from @t2 t2 
             where t2.value>0 
                and t.date1>=t2.date_2 
                and t.ID=t2.ID
             order by t2.date_2 desc) t2
```

**Removed Result Set**

Comment: what if there are multiple records for `id` in `table`? for example, 2 records for `id` `1`

Comment: Your logic had no regard to ID. With this logic all records for table 1 will be returned with a corresponding values from table2 where value is not 0 and the equal or next lower date available. If none are valid then nulls are returned with the outer apply

Comment: my apologies - should i repost the question?

Comment: what is the new logic? I am assuming this has to do with table 2?

Comment: The new logic is if there is a second record for `id` `1`. so currently, with two records for that `id`, the same `date_2` is being returned

Comment: I don't follow. add more records to your example tables, so that what you are conveying shows in the updated results.

Comment: That should do it. You just have to set ID=ID as well